# Scale border width depending on text length

Tags: css

im learning css and not very good at it at the moment. Is there a way to scale the border width depending on the text width as a user could input a short name or a long one. This is the CSS of the border. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
#summonerInfo{
  border:2px solid black;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

[image]

edit: I was new to CSS, after some googling just set `width:auto;` and that will automatically set the correct borders.

Comment: I am guessing you don't want to actually "scale the border width", but to make the _element_ itself grow wider, if the text content demands it? Set a `min-width` instead of a width then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set width to auto; width:auto; it will try to keep the contents inside the allocated box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).